# SQL Server: No Guid of a database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I built a powershell script for collecting database information with the help of the class "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server". My script
run into an error because one database has no DatabaseGuid. How could that happen?
I thought every database has a database guid?!
This database is in state "offline". I set an other database to state "offline" but the database has still a guid.

I thought each database reaceives a persistent guid, or?!

Thanks

Comment: From what table(s) are you trying to retrieve a `DatabaseGuid`?  Please post your script(s).  Also, update your question (or tags) to identify the version of SQL Server you're using.  (2016, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

From this post: [Obtaining a unique database identifier for SQL Server 2005 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916991/obtaining-a-unique-database-identifier-for-sql-server-2005-and-later)
 it seems that

> probably SMO reads the `database_guid` value from
>   `sys.database_recovery_status`:
>
> Used to relate all the database files of a database together. All
>   files must have this GUID in their header page for the database to
>   start as expected. Only one database should ever have this GUID, but
>   duplicates can be created by copying and attaching databases. RESTORE
>   always generates a new GUID when you restore a database that does not
>   yet exist.

And if you open the documentation [sys.database_recovery_status (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-recovery-status-transact-sql) you'll find that

> NULL= Database is **offline**, or the database will not start.

I tried to put some my databases offline and to query `database_guid` from  `sys.database_recovery_status` and it is `NULL` while it's `not NULL` when bring these databases online again.